# JToken.ReadFrom vs JToken.Load?

Tags: json.net

The Json.net documentation between these 2 methods are exactly the same.

- [JToken.ReadFrom](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ReadFrom.htm)
- [JToken.Load](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Load.htm)

Both are static methods.  Both have the same signatures.

Is there a preferred method?  Does one depend on the next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are functionally identical.

In the abstract `JToken` class, `Load` ultimately calls `ReadFrom`, which figures out which type of `JToken` is being read and then delegates to the `Load` methods of the concrete subclasses as appropriate.  `JArray`, `JObject`, `JProperty` and `JConstrutor` all have their own versions of `Load` which hide `JToken.Load` and create and return that object type (i.e. `JObject.Load` creates a `JObject`, etc.)  Note that `JValue` does not have a `Load` method of its own, so that is handled in `JToken.ReadFrom`.

You can see for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs):

```
public static JToken Load(JsonReader reader)
{
    return Load(reader, null);
}

public static JToken Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings? settings)
{
    return ReadFrom(reader, settings);
}

public static JToken ReadFrom(JsonReader reader)
{
    return ReadFrom(reader, null);
}

public static JToken ReadFrom(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings? settings)
{
    ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(reader, nameof(reader));

    ...        

    switch (reader.TokenType)
    {
        case JsonToken.StartObject:
            return JObject.Load(reader, settings);
        case JsonToken.StartArray:
            return JArray.Load(reader, settings);
        case JsonToken.StartConstructor:
            return JConstructor.Load(reader, settings);
        case JsonToken.PropertyName:
            return JProperty.Load(reader, settings);
        case JsonToken.String:
        case JsonToken.Integer:
        case JsonToken.Float:
        case JsonToken.Date:
        case JsonToken.Boolean:
        case JsonToken.Bytes:
            JValue v = new JValue(reader.Value);
            v.SetLineInfo(lineInfo, settings);
            return v;
        case JsonToken.Comment:
            v = JValue.CreateComment(reader.Value!.ToString());
            v.SetLineInfo(lineInfo, settings);
            return v;
        case JsonToken.Null:
            v = JValue.CreateNull();
            v.SetLineInfo(lineInfo, settings);
            return v;
        case JsonToken.Undefined:
            v = JValue.CreateUndefined();
            v.SetLineInfo(lineInfo, settings);
            return v;
        default:
            throw JsonReaderException.Create(reader, "Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Unexpected token: {0}".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, reader.TokenType));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian... very helpful!